CS50 PSet 7 Movies (9.sql )
Why this code doesn't work? It should output 19.325 rows. I only get 4 rows. Meanwhile, it worked well when I used JOIN
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM people
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT person_id
    FROM stars
    WHERE movie_id =
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM movies
        WHERE year = 2004
    )
);


The error you get is probably related to movie_id = ( SELECT id FROM movies WHERE year = 2004 ). You probably have more then 1 movie in 2004 so the assignment is invalid. Look into using JOIN instead of movie_id = (some select statement).

As Bart mentioned in the comment above the problem is in strict filter on movie_id:
WHERE movie_id IN ( SELECT id FROM movies WHERE year = 2004 ) );

I know you mentioned JOINs, so you are aware of them. But just for the reference:
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM people
JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE movies.year = 2004
;

